# what does "n-faces" mean in n-Simplex elements table?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, machine-learning

The convex hull of any nonempty subset of the n + 1 points that define an n-simplex is called a face of the [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).

[image]

In the case of triangle `0-faces (vertices)` is 3, which is reasonable, a triangle has 3 vertices, and `1-faces (edges)` could be interpreted as that a triangle has 3 edges, the question is

what does `2-faces = 1` mean?

in the case of tetrahedron, `2-faces = 4` and `3-faces = 1`, where do they come from?

Comment: The 2-face of the triangle is the whole thing. 2-faces are faces that have 3 vertices. So there are 4 triangular faces of the tetrahedron.

Answer (score 1):

An $n$-face is just a $k$-face where $n=k$.

So what's a $k$-face?

Following the definition of a face in your first sentence, for any $k=0,...,n$, and for any $k+1$ element subset of the given set of $n+1$ points, the convex hull of that subset is a face of the given $n$-simplex. Furthermore, if I apply the definition of a simplex (unstated in your post), that face is itself a $k$-simplex.

So the sensible definition is that a $k$-face is a face that is a $k$-simplex.

Then the question arises: how many $k$-faces are there in an $n$-simplex? This is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833758/what-are-the-formulas-for-the-number-of-vertices-edges-faces-cells-4-faces?rq=1), but I'll spell it out in a bit more detail. This number is the same as the number of $k+1$ element subsets of an $n+1$ element set, which is the same as the [number of combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of $n+1$ things taken $k+1$ at a time, which is given by the formula
$$\frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)! \, ((n+1)-(k+1))!} = \frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)! \, (n-k)!}
$$

For example, for $n=3$ and $k=1$, in the given set of $n+1=4$ points there are exactly six subsets with $k+1=2$ points. This comes from the formula for combinations of $4$ things taken $2$ at a time: 
$$\frac{4!}{2! (4-2)!}=6
$$
Therefore a $3$-simplex has exactly six $1$-faces.

When $k=n$, there is just one $n+1$ element subset of the given set of $n+1$ points, namely the whole set. And so there is just one $n$-face of the given $n$-simplex, namely the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

The idea stems - much more general than the above explanation for the simplices, which then indeed is related to the Pascal triangle, aka binomial coefficients - from the generalisation of the **Euler formula**.

For convex polyhedra you probably know the form $V-E+F=2$, i.e. the number of vertices ($V$) minus the number of edges ($E$) plus the number of faces ($F$) equals 2. If you would use quite generally $f_k$ to be the number of $k$-faces ($k$-dimensional elements), you would get for some $d$-dimensional polytope the dimensionally generalised formula
$$1-(-1)^d=\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}(-1)^k f_k$$
This very formula could even become much nicer, if we'd define $f_{-1}=1$ (kind of saying there is a unique nullitope, an empty element, associated to the polytope, which furthermore is incident to all vertices) and we also would define $f_d=1$ as well (kind of saying there would be a unique $d$-volume, the polytope itself). For then we can simply write
$$0=\sum_{k=-1}^d(-1)^k f_k$$
A different explanation would occur in the context of **Hasse diagram**. Here you represent each symmetry inequivalent type of elements (e.g. differentiating between triangles and squares etc., within the polygonal faces) by a node. and you connect those nodes via the incidence relations. Again, when adding those extremal elements $f_{-1}$ and $f_d$, then those Hasse diagrams get the nice topology of what also becomes known an antitegum(*). Within a Hasse diagram every subelement gets represented by the sub diagram between that elemental representing node and the nullitopal node. Furthermore any polytopal vertex-, edge-, etc. -figure's Hasse diagram is given by the subdiagram between the elementals representing node and the bulk- or $d$-volume node.

(*) In 3D the antitegum is the dual of an antiprism.

--- rk