# Counting number of n-faces in a uniform 7-polytope

Tags: geometry, polytopes

Building off of [What are the formulas for the number of vertices, edges, faces, cells, 4-faces, ..., $n$-faces, of convex regular polytopes in $n \geq 5$ dimensions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833758/what-are-the-formulas-for-the-number-of-vertices-edges-faces-cells-4-faces) ,

Are there formulas for the number of 6-faces, 5-faces, 4-faces, etc for an arbitrary 7-polytope? For example, the Hexipentiruncitruncated_7-simplex wikipedia page below is  blank except for the edges and the vertices. Do methods exist to calculate the number of 6 faces, 5 faces, 4 faces?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexicated_7-simplexes#Hexipentiruncitruncated_7-simplex

Comment: For an *aribtrary* $7$-polytope? I mean, even for an arbitrary polygon you have no control on the number of edges. I'm not sure what you're asking here, unless you're specifically interested in the example you linked, but it sounded like not.

Comment: Sorry, not for an arbitrary 7-polytope, I'm saying that if I'm interested in the example provided, are there existing methods to figure out the number of n-faces?

Comment: In that case: definitely yes. This example is an orbit polytope of the symmetric group, so [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152589/how-to-find-faces-of-polytope-defined-by-a-weyl-orbit) applies. But I'll try to see what the difficulty is with running it on this example, or else write an answer :P

Comment: (More generally, this is a less refined question than determining the face poset of a polytope, and I imagine that if you truncate a polytope and you already know the face poset of the original then you have some easy way of computing the face poset of the truncation. But I really don't know enough about polytopes to be able to spit out an answer without doing some reading)